# Get rid of Tab elevation in Android

Tags: android

I have the following problem: I have built a ViewPager with an Android Tab bar and I want to remove the elevation of the tab bar. It's the black line that I either want to be removed or to be the same as the color of the tab bar and I want no elevation: please see following picture (I want to get rid of the black line the error is showing):

[image]

I have tried the following:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp"
            app:tabBackground="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:elevation="0dp"
            />
```

But none of these variations seem to work.

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: Is your TabLayout inside an AppBarLayout?

Comment: @DanielNugent yes it is

Comment: Set elevation to `0dp` on the AppBarLayout

Comment: @DanielNugent since we are talking about tabs could you help me out with one more question please with Tabs please ? I want the tabindicator (the white line that is beneath the tabs) to be shorter. I only know how to set the height however I am struggling with setting a shorter length